# How to generate firebase registration token in android

Tags: android, firebase

I have integrated firebase as a backend in my android app.I am trying to change users device id every time app opens.

I am using below code to get firebase registration id:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                return;
            }

            // Get Instance ID token
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

How can I change this token every time users open an app.
Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55558366/7254873

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration token may change when:

- The app deletes Instance ID
- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

Read the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

You can revoke the token from server and notify the device. 
The procedure is well explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation_in_database_rules).